# What is reduce use for when you are not accumulating anything

Tags: javascript

```
reducers.reduce(
  (p, r) => r(p, current),
  previous,
);
```

Reducer is an array of functions `r(p, current)` will return an object. I am trying to understand the source code from here https://github.com/dvajs/dva/blob/master/packages/dva-core/src/handleActions.js but is a bit confuse with this statement. What is it reducing to?

I have tried to play around with the `reduce` function and it seems it is just taking the last value (If I am not transformation the value just like in this case)?

```js
var array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3];
const result = array1.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => currentValue);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Read about it [**on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and check out its pollyfill code for better understanding.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thank you. I actually read it thats where the snippet is from.

Comment: It is not clear that no accumulation occurs from the example you've posted, in that example, `p` could be modified inside the `r` function and returned by this function.

Comment: @Titus from what I know, r(p, current) is a pure function that will produce an immutable object

Comment: `previous` _is_ the accumulator. Look at the original code again.

Comment: @Andy I would say `previous` is the initial value and `p` is the accumulator. Am I right?

Comment: `previous` is set as the initial value which is in itself the accumulator - it's passed into the reduce function on each iteration as `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, yes, the result of `.reduce()` is the last returned value from the accumulator function.

In your example, because you're just returning the current value, the last of those is going to be your result.

If you actually did something to the value, you would see a change. For example, here is a quick example which sums all values in the array:

```js
const sum = [1,2,3,4,5].reduce((result, current) => result + current, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

In the first snippet, it's likely looping over the array `reducers`, which is probably an array of functions which transform the value, with each `r` returning the result of the transformation.

This is a fairly common pattern for performing arbitrary actions over data (Redux is another common library off the top of my head that uses this pattern).

Comment: So in this case I am not really accumulating anything. I dont understand why they use this pattern, why not just a simple for loop?

Comment: They are "accumulating" something though, though it's really a transform. `p` is the result of their accumulation, which is likely returned by `r()`. They're transforming `p` over and over and returning the final result. You could use a loop, but you'd be constantly setting `p = r(p, current)`, which is exactly what `reduce()` is for.

Comment: but if you look at the source code, on line 10 and 12 is the only place they return object. They are not mutating the object but instead returning new object. So no transformation is happening to `p`. `r(p, current)` will always return something new. I am right to say this?

Comment: Yes and no. With an immutable, you never change (mutate) the existing object. So, since the function is dealing with immutables, it is returning a new object each time. However, each time, `p` is the immutable made by the last loop. If it wasn't an immutable, it would be a more traditional transform. With immutables, it is still technically a transform, though each transform results in a new object with the previous unchanged.

Comment: I can see the picture clearly now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Zanko, I added some additional information you might find useful.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little easier to understand when you look at the whole function rather than the section you quoted:

```
function reduceReducers(...reducers) {
  return (previous, current) =>
    reducers.reduce(
      (p, r) => r(p, current),
      previous,
    );
}
```

...and what happens when the function is called:

```
const reducer = reduceReducers(...reducers);
```

`reduceReducers(...reducers)` returns a *function* that, when called with `reducer(state, action)` takes a state as the initial value/array and passes which is used as the accumulator `p`. `action` is passed in as `current` whereupon the reducer `r` is called presumably creating a new state based on the action.

Let's take another look, this time annotated:

```
// `reduceReducer` takes an array of reducers
function reduceReducers(...reducers) {

  // It returns a new function that accepts 2 arguments:
  // `previous` and `current`
  // This function is assigned to the variable `reducer`
  return (previous, current) =>

    // `reducers` can still be called here because of
    // the closure that formed - the returned function
    // maintains its outer lexical environment
    reducers.reduce(

      // On each iteration the accumulator is passed in.
      // In the initial iteration this is the value of `state`
      // On each iteration the value of the next reducer called with
      // the new state and the action is returned
      (p, r) => r(p, current),

      // `previous` is passed in as the initial value
      // When `reducer` is called `reducer(state, action)`
      // this means that `state` is `previous`
      previous,
    );
}
```

Hope this is a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks! Does `previous` get populated by closure? It will never be changed right?

Comment: Think of it like this: `reducer(state is previous, action is current)`

Comment: I see the other tricky thing is to recognize that `reducers` can still be called due to closure. Does closure really provide any benefit in this case? the function could have been written as `function reduceReducers(previous, current, ...reducers) {` ? I guess they want to return a function instead of running the function?

Comment: It's basically making use of functions as first-class objects for better code reuse, and better functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Reduce is very helpful in some cases.
below is the example where you want to find out the sum of all elements in an array.

```js
var input = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var output = input.reduce(function(sum, item) {
  return sum += item;
})
console.log(output);
```